What's the difference (if any) between "self" and "consciousness"?
Definitions
Philosophy of self

The philosophy of self examines the idea of the self at a conceptual level. Many different ideas on what constitutes self have been proposed, including the self being an activity, the self being independent of the senses, the bundle theory of the self, the self as a narrative center of gravity, and the self as a linguistic or social construct rather than a physical entity. The self (or its non-existence) is also an important concept in Eastern philosophy, including Buddhist philosophy.
Source: Wikipedia: Philosphy of Self

Self

In philosophy, the self is an individual's own being, knowledge, and values, and the relationship between these attributes.
The first-person perspective distinguishes selfhood from personal identity. Whereas "identity" is (literally) sameness[1] and may involve categorization and labeling,[2] selfhood implies a first-person perspective and suggests potential uniqueness. Conversely, "person" is used as a third-person reference. Personal identity can be impaired in late-stage Alzheimer's disease and in other neurodegenerative diseases. Finally, the self is distinguishable from "others". Including the distinction between sameness and otherness, the self versus other is a research topic in contemporary philosophy[3] and contemporary phenomenology (see also psychological phenomenology), psychology, psychiatry, neurology, and neuroscience.
Although subjective experience is central to selfhood, the privacy of this experience is only one of many problems in the philosophy of self and scientific study of consciousness.
Source: Wikipedia: Self

Consciousness

An animal, person or other cognitive system may be regarded as
conscious in a number of different senses.
Sentience. It may be conscious in the generic sense of simply being a
sentient creature, one capable of sensing and responding to its world
(Armstrong 1981). Being conscious in this sense may admit of degrees,
and just what sort of sensory capacities are sufficient may not be
sharply defined. Are fish conscious in the relevant respect? And what
of shrimp or bees?
Wakefulness. One might further require that the organism actually be
exercising such a capacity rather than merely having the ability or
disposition to do so. Thus one might count it as conscious only if it
were awake and normally alert. In that sense organisms would not count
as conscious when asleep or in any of the deeper levels of coma. Again
boundaries may be blurry, and intermediate cases may be involved. For
example, is one conscious in the relevant sense when dreaming,
hypnotized or in a fugue state?
Self-consciousness. A third and yet more demanding sense might define
conscious creatures as those that are not only aware but also aware
that they are aware, thus treating creature consciousness as a form of
self-consciousness (Carruthers 2000). The self-awareness requirement
might get interpreted in a variety of ways, and which creatures would
qualify as conscious in the relevant sense will vary accordingly. If
it is taken to involve explicit conceptual self-awareness, many
non-human animals and even young children might fail to qualify, but
if only more rudimentary implicit forms of self-awareness are required
then a wide range of nonlinguistic creatures might count as
self-conscious.
What it is like. Thomas Nagel's (1974) famous“what it is like”
criterion aims to capture another and perhaps more subjective notion
of being a conscious organism. According to Nagel, a being is
conscious just if there is “something that it is like” to be that
creature, i.e., some subjective way the world seems or appears from
the creature's mental or experiential point of view. In Nagel's
example, bats are conscious because there is something that it is like
for a bat to experience its world through its echo-locatory senses,
even though we humans from our human point of view can not
emphatically understand what such a mode of consciousness is like from
the bat's own point of view.
Subject of conscious states. A fifth alternative would be to define
the notion of a conscious organism in terms of conscious states. That
is, one might first define what makes a mental state a conscious
mental state, and then define being a conscious creature in terms of
having such states. One's concept of a conscious organism would then
depend upon the particular account one gives of conscious states
(section 2.2).
Transitive Consciousness. In addition to describing creatures as
conscious in these various senses, there are also related senses in
which creatures are described as being conscious of various things.
The distinction is sometimes marked as that between transitive and
intransitive notions of consciousness, with the former involving some
object at which consciousness is directed (Rosenthal 1986).
Source: SEP: Consciousness


Motivation/Context
Recently a question about self was closed as a duplicate of a question about consciousness. On meta someone defended the closure by arguing:

From Google's definition of self:

a person's essential being that distinguishes them from others, especially considered as the object of introspection or reflexive
action.

So, yes, on a canonical reading, the self is a product of
self-consciousness. Note, the original question was something along
the lines of "Is the self an illusion?". Since the "self" and
"self-awareness" and "consciousness" are all intimately related in
philosophy of mind, the questions were close enough to warrant my
personal VTC.

To provide further support for the close conceptual overlap between self and consciousness, they also quoted a paragraph from SEP, Self-Consciousness:

Human beings are conscious not only of the world around them but also of themselves: their activities, their bodies, and their mental lives. They are, that is, self-conscious (or, equivalently, self-aware). Self-consciousness can be understood as an awareness of oneself. But a self-conscious subject is not just aware of something that merely happens to be themselves, as one is if one sees an old photograph without realising that it is of oneself. Rather a self-conscious subject is aware of themselves as themselves; it is manifest to them that they themselves are the object of awareness. Self-consciousness is a form of consciousness that is paradigmatically expressed in English by the words “I”, “me”, and “my”, terms that each of us uses to refer to ourselves as such.


Question
The conceptual overlap between self and consciousness is undeniable. The quoted definition of consciousness from the SEP includes six senses, one of which is self-consciousness, as referenced by the answer from meta. However, this is only one of six possible senses, and it seems dubious to leap from "consciousness may possibly include self-consciousness" to "consciousness and self are the same thing," especially without first establishing that self and self-consciousness are the same thing. On the other hand, the Wikipedia definition of self states that "subjective experience is central to selfhood," which could be interpreted as suggesting that consciousness is central to selfhood. However, X being central to Y doesn’t necessarily imply that X = Y.
According to knowledgeable philosophers specializing in philosophy of mind:
What is the difference (if any) between "self" and "consciousness"? To what extent are these concepts interchangeable? To what extent does one entail the other, or vice versa?

@andre I'm open to suggestions to improve the quality.

Newborn babies are conscious but have no sense of "self".

There is an entire section of Infant Psychology and Development that deals with self-awareness.  Sure. It's a philosophy question too, but psychology includes empirical evidence.

I would say that self requires persistence across time, where consciousness could refer to a single moment.

The difference depends on the definition. But the most familiar sort of self, the feeling of being a subject peering out through the eyes of what seems to be a body you can control, cannot be the same as being conscious. This is because a feeling is a part of consciousness, and the part cannot be the same as the whole. Thus, the self is an object within consciousness, which is what centuries of Buddhist meditators have alluded to.
The self is apparent when one recognizes itself. Babies and many other animals cannot recognize themselves in front of the mirror initially. This self awareness comes well more than a year after a human baby’s birth as studies have shown. See here.
Consciousness on the other hand is fundamental. If there are any sensations at all, there is consciousness. There are arguably moments even in your adult life where there is consciousness but perhaps no feeling of being a subject: such as being immersed in a movie or being focused in a sport where the feeling of being a subject goes away. This is also known as the state of flow.

+1: This. Self implies consciousness, but not the other way around.

Original Answer
The distinction between self and not-self arises within the domain of consciousness. The distinction between conscious and unconscious arises within the domain of consciousness. Consciousness appears to be necessary to recognize, describe, and discuss such distinctions.
One can further argue that the biological process generates cognitive distinctions operating below the level of consciousness in the so-called domain of the subconscious or unconscious. Hermann von Helmholtz makes compelling arguments for cognitive operations that he called unconscious inference. In that context one can argue for the existence of Philosophical Zombies who act as if they are conscious humans but perform cognition without experiencing consciousness.
EDIT - Self and Mind
Antonio Damasio is a neuroscientist who writes books about human emotions, consciousness, and problems of the mind. This TED Talk has the title: The quest to understand consciousness
https://www.ted.com/talks/antonio_damasio_the_quest_to_understand_consciousness/transcript?subtitle=en
The arguments made by Damasio, and other advocates of embodied cognition, are that conscious minds emerge from the structures and functions of the brain, and the emergence of consciousness is such that there is a self in the mind. Damasio promotes this using the title: Self Comes To Mind.

You ask:

What is the difference (if any) between "self" and "consciousness"? To what extent are these concepts interchangeable? To what extent does one entail the other, or vice versa?

They are not very interchangeable at all. They are both, however, aspects of a phenomenon Franz Bretano wrote about called intentionality (SEP).  It seems like you are trying to scaffold out an ontology of mind. There is no canonical description of the mind. In the philosophy of mind, there are a number of different approaches to describing the mind, be it functionalist, identity theorist, non-reductive physicalist, property dualist, etc. But all of these metaphysical theories are highly derived from a contentious, but relatively similar ontology: intentionality, consciousness, self-consciousness, awareness, phenomena, qualia, introspection, and self-knowledge, to name a few.
Intentionality (SEP) is the property of minds (and software according to some) to be about something else, often called also 'aboutness'. The mind, in this sense, mirrors the world, and that approach when fortified with positivist thinking (the idea that our mind engenders naive or direct realism) is often considered a "thing" that builds representations.The broad term for the process that entails intentionality is consciousness (SEP), and there are a number of different approaches. Consider all of the representational theories of consciousness (SEP). More specifically, since cognitivism began displacing behaviorism about the time a cheeky but intelligent linguist by the name of Chomsky came around, electromechanical computers were a source of inspiration for some who have offered a computational theory of mind (SEP).
It's important to understand that such views of the mind so far are largely offered in the analytic tradition, and that among the so-called Continental thinkers, phenomenology (SEP) offers a different persuasion of philosophy of mind. And representationalist notions of mind and philosophy are questioned by some sometimes post-analytical philosophers like Rorty in his neo-pragmatism who takes the linguistic turn to an extreme. And both the analytical thinkers (Frege, Russell, etc.) and the Continental (Husserl, Heidegger, etc.) trace their philosophy of mind back to Kant's transcendental idealism. So, it's not uncommon to see the words "broadly Kantian" or "neo-Kantian" applied to all sorts of philosophers of mind. Anyway...
If there's an apparent duality of body and mind, and mind seems to come and go with sleep, then intentionality is generally attributed to consciousness in rough measure. Consciousness is the aspect of the mind that seems to disappear every night, and seems to be a property of the mind. There have, of course, been terms such as unconscious and subconscious offered to talk about what happens when consciousness ceases, and the former is regarded as largely pseudoscientific as it is Freudian in mind. Subconscious is generally useful in describing what are now understood as processes of the brain that might form the basis of intuition (SEP). John Searle likes the term 'The Background'. Whatever you call it, it's the part of the mind that is beyond introspection (SEP).
See, consciousness, the process that entails us (and for AGI dreamers sentient machines) having intentionality, seems to be quite a complicated affair, and it can be directed at objects, and this ability to be predicated of things is often called awareness to distinguish it. In psychology, attention is the term used to operationalize the aboutness of our aboutness. Sometimes our aboutness can be about the external world, and sometimes it's about ourselves. For instance, we can have bodily awareness (SEP). We can also broaden the notion to combine, roughly speaking, both introspection of thoughts and bodily awareness to self-consciousness (SEP). When that happens (and for some of us on the OC spectrum we cannot stop it short of self-obliteration), we start to develop a notion of 'self', which might be understood in psychological terms as personality.
Whether you call it 'the self', 'my personality', 'I, me, and my: the royal we', what we are dealing with is a complex of self-knowledge (SEP). If you are a compulsive thinker, you've probably gone through an existential crisis as you start to see your self in a more complex relationship to the society and world around you. Psychologists have a clinical term as the self develops called individuation and humanist psychologists a la Maslow speak of the peak of continued development of the self self-actualization. Whatever the details, the idea is the self which arises from consciousness is a unique entity that transcends material being.
Of course, in the olden days, before the Old English words 'eald dagas' were even coined, such notion of the uniqueness of self have been called psyche and pneuma in Greek or anima and spiritus in Latin, though today, we tout 'soul' from those pesky Anglo-Saxons who used 'seola'. So, consciousness of ourselves and the world around us gives rise to the self is a scientific explanation, one that has displaced for many (though certainly not all) the notion that our selves are given to us by supernatural forces such as the Hebrew Yaweh.
So to reiterate, consciousness is the process and experience by which the self, often taken to be one's personal identity (SEP), is derived. There is of course no shortage of ways to complicate the conversation. We can talk about self-knowledge in regards to externalism (SEP). We can extend the locus of consciousness beyond the brain such as in embodied and external cognition (SEP), and we can talk about how sometimes the self is enmeshed in the mutual identity and politics (SEP) of those around us. But those are the broad strokes.
If you're interested in this stuff, consider getting John Heil's 4th edition of Philosophy of Mind: An Introduction (GB). It will get you started on the road to getting technical to philosophy of mind topics. I also like my copy of Blackwell's A Companion to the Philosophy of Mind ed. by Samuel Gutternplan. It has a list of terminological entries that surpass a typical philosophical dictionary, and the entries are written by some rather outstanding thinkers including Searle, Dennett, Block, Dretske, Lewis, Fodor, Kim, and others. (And never take closure personally. Sometimes, that's just the way the cookie crumbles.)

'Consciousness' is a basic field of awareness. This includes perceptions that we associate with the external world (the five basic senses) and perceptions we associate with internal world (physical sensations, gut feelings, emotions, thoughts, etc). To be conscious means to be capable of perception.
'Self' is a mental construct developed to organize interactions with the elements perceived in consciousness. An infant is fully aware of everything — i.e., is conscious — but cannot organize its perceptions to understand and control its own body, differentiate between people and objects, or grasp the difference between internal and external perceptions. Over time that infant develops a self by organizing its perceptions and learning to control and work with them: e.g., discovering that this is 'its' leg, and can be consciously moved 'like so'.

Good answer except we can imagine the distinction between self and not-self to be innate in the subconscious functions of the body or to be an emergent distinction arising via interaction between the body and its surroundings to become a conscious and subconscious function. I don't remember details of experiments to determine how babies respond to self-touch versus other-touch or show evidence of distinction between self and others. But I recall vaguely experiments that suggest (subject to interpretation) the child can distinguish between self-touch and other-touch at a very early age.

@SystemTheory: I don't doubt that infants respond differently to self-touch and other-touch because those touches involve different sets of sensations (self-touch creates sensations in both the hand and the place touched). They can certainly recognize different sensations, but that doesn't necessarily mean they organize those sensations into different attributive models like 'self' and 'other'. Those are cognitive structures that are developed, not innate. But even if there is some innate difference, it's no more than a kernel around which a proper sense of self is built.

So you get my point. We can make observations, and draw inferences, derived from our own experience of self and not-self, and yet we still can't verify for certain because the unconscious mind may generate such distinctions even in the newborn.

@SystemTheory: Talking about an 'unconscious mind' in newborns isn't consistent with either the original the psychoanalytic model the concept derives from nor the more modern and limited use of the term has in cognitive psychology. I'm not sure how you're using the term, of course, but in any case I don't think this has much bearing on my point.

The father of psychoanalysis, Sigmund Freud, describes the newborn psyche as the biological source of inner drives (the id), the biological consciousness (the ego), and external reality (reality). Ego is the function which makes efforts to govern action in the sensory context. The human newborn ego is helpless. The internal id and external reality are originally unconscious. The id and reality remain entirely unconscious, however, the ego becomes conscious of id/reality due to perceptions that seem to be caused by the unconscious not-ego! Freud argues id/ego in the biological unconscious!

@SystemTheory: Ah, me, we're back to this again. I get that you like to argue — lots of people do — but I like arguments to be a bit more purposive than this. So I'll step away from this conversation too.

AI Overview (google) - In psychoanalysis, the "primary narcissism" debate centers around the concept that infants initially experience a state of complete self-absorption, where they perceive themselves as the center of the universe, and gradually develop the capacity to recognize and relate to others; this concept is largely attributed to Sigmund Freud, but is contested by later psychoanalytic theorists who argue that the infant's early self is not entirely self-focused and is inherently relational from the beginning, questioning the idea of a fully isolated "primary narcissistic" phase.
